# Solr calculate last day of month

Tags: solr, schema

I am building a Solr
Index where data has date I need to calculate a field if date was last day of month?

I would prefer if I can do
It at query time, tried few things unsuccessfully any ideas

Answer (score 0):

if you mean 'a field that says if the date in another field is the last day of THAT month', then it makes much more sense to do it at index time:

1. it will be more performant, you index it as a boolean, and no calculation needs to happen at query time, just matching it
2. you have several of ways to compute it: at the client side (the easiest), in a UpdateRequestProcessor, tansformer if you are doing DIH,
   maybe some crazy regex can do it in a copyfield...

Comment: I am sure it is more performant, what I need is to classify data on quarters six monthly and yearly boundaries as a report

Comment: Or may be with date math such a conclusion can be inferred